# java.net.MalformedURLException while connecting to Window Live Oauth

Tags: java, oauth, oauth-2.0, scribe

I am using scribe java API for Oauth service and i am able to work perfectly with Gmail and Facebook but when it comes to Window live service i am strucked.
i am following the standard code whihc is working perfectly fine for other services.i am able to get access token from window live 
but when i am trying to access the service to get user profile i am getting

```
java.net.MalformedURLException
```

here is the exception log message

```
org.scribe.exceptions.OAuthException: Problems while creating connection.
    org.scribe.model.Request.send(Request.java:71)
    org.scribe.model.OAuthRequest.send(OAuthRequest.java:12)
......
......

java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me?access_token=EwAoAq1DBAAUlbRWyAJjK5w968Ru3Cyt%5C%2F6GvwXwAAdfi2SDJuwJlMd29Za96amS5o2UFyXbtnIZglVJKxdimcPb2yYie966goCS2%2ByCjrWBpgUUUphkhYwFyFiN8I2J3pdyg4IQlbG%2BD8U%5C%2F9q5M5iU1q6niqYldYYOyq3ZpNw95l3oFdefQBlnEesequMhHhTVw%2B0ku93xc06lnULgYbVubTWqT8zBzwgHRie93CSDl1wUWQAYe2TzAAk9iIsBvmTmiICdWFrFpZrmpBS3VOec9zdarXuloaXI1IEPA5fDT%2B04RF8uUi1AukmRfjr%2B4C2J8fg8wbRQguMlZNLwG9fleixl2MLcA18ZOkHS%2Bu2eS5BcDYzCfOI8YJ9zf9IGUDZgAACLp7RJwAG8gk%2BAAFtLOh0pYNNGb3AtyjyurJowo014DLmKLLQfjeB0Lz3Nnwd0oBSv0g0qAT8qvdlLlVNyvgg3weqYiR%2BxD%2Bl8kX0SFBX7unVAkiloyqme7D4lNSM25wnJJrmc8wgop5x12MxwtuAOx3IXaNijCkyqtyVRfpU%2BVYv%5C%2FyH5JRuKOEia%2BX00%5C%2FEeWOXOP%5C%2F1yL9zYpRDaBpgOlZ7gBY6Q45buBjaGWsAi4Zg7QSDZeaFkMrIkVaWhhOdpNArXfUnDWAezlLqQZF0Otl8%5C%2F9%2BP3hel0mR7noFaMG0o57kV%2Bnm%2BhzF8LgCZleJCVdxC19ZmhrLM%5C%2FKTTEkAYHQWXhLQAA
    java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    java.net.URL.<init>(Unknown Source)
    org.scribe.model.Request.createConnection(Request.java:81)
    org.scribe.model.Request.send(Request.java:62)
    org.scribe.model.OAuthRequest.send(OAuthRequest.java:12)
    com.raisonne.oauth.action.OAuthCallbackHandlerAction.OtherCallBackHandler(OAuthCallbackHandlerAction.java:101)
    com.raisonne.oauth.action.OAuthCallbackHandlerAction.execute(OAuthCallbackHandlerAction.java:50)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:452)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invokeActionOnly(DefaultActionInvocation.java:291)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:254)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:138)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:270)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:145)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:171)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.I18nInterceptor.intercept(I18nInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.ServletConfigInterceptor.intercept(ServletConfigInterceptor.java:164)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.AliasInterceptor.intercept(AliasInterceptor.java:190)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ExceptionMappingInterceptor.intercept(ExceptionMappingInterceptor.java:187)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.execute(StrutsActionProxy.java:52)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:498)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
    org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
```

i am clueless what is going wrong for a API which is working fine as while debugging for other applicaation its creating same URL pattern

```
connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(effectiveUrl).openConnection();
```

this is the line in API where it throwing the exception

Comment: Not sure but plz check the double quote printed just before https is part of exception trace, or you have that thing in URL string being passed.

Comment: see the answer of Pablo Fernandez, i am 100% sure there is some problem in your URL double check it

Comment: It's strange because the exception message says "no protocol", but the message also prints the URL and the URL definitely does have a protocol.

Comment: @Michael: problem was with the leading `"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, this is not a problem of using `HttpURLConnection`, because:

1. `HttpsURLConnection` is a subtype of `HttpURLConnection`
2. If that were the case, it would definitely throw a class cast
   exception instead

Check the URL you're passing, my guess is that it looks like this:

`"\"https://..."` (Note that you have a preceding `"` but not a trailing one on the URL)

Answer (score -1):

Since your URL uses the "https" protocol, you must use the `HttpsURLConnection` class, not the `HttpURLConnection` class.

Comment: problem is i am using that third party API so have to look in to how  i can ask to switch to https

Comment: This is __so not true__ since `HttpsURLConnection` inherits from `HttpURLConnection`